# gremlin-python: what is a valid vertex custom id?

Tags: python, gremlin, janusgraph

I want to add a vertex to `JanusGraph` by `GremlinPython`, and I already set `graph.set-vertex-id=true` in config, but I always get error:`GremlinServerError: 500: Not a valid vertex id: 5678`

I want to set a custom id to vertex, I only know the `id` should be a `long` type, some `id` set success, like:2048, 123456...; But more `id` set failed, it raise a error: `GremlinServerError: 500: Not a valid vertex id: 5678`.

My add vertex code is:
`vip = g.addV().property(T.id, 5678).property("name", "domain").property("value", "www.google.com").next()`

Please tell me what is a valid id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **UUID** with `T.id` ...

```
>>> from uuid import UUID
>>> vip = g.addV().property(T.id, UUID(int=5678)).property("name", "domain").property("value", "www.google.com").next()
>>> vip
v[00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000162e]
>>> 0x162e
5678
```

Answer (score 0):

The type is Long, but you need to send it in a string.

> vip = g.addV().property(T.id, '5678').property("name", "domain").....